# Cómo calcular el Máximo Común Divisor de dos numeros enteros

Tags: c++

Un ejercicio me pide realizar una función que calcule el máximo común divisor entre los dos numeros enteros que introduces en el programa al ejecutarse.

Yo lo he hecho de la siguiente manera, pero creo que se puede optimizar y hacerlo mejor. Sobretodo en relación con el uso de variables de referencia en la función. Creo que se puede hacer mas corto.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;


int GCD(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cout << "Integer 1:\n";
    cin >> x;

    cout << "Integer 2:\n";
    cin >> y;

    cout << "GCD(" << x << "," << y << "): " << GCD(x, y);

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

int GCD(int x, int y)
{
    int ref;
    int maxdiv;
    x > y ? ref = x : ref = y;

    for (int i{ 1 }; i < ref; i++)
    {
        if (x % i == 0 && y % i == 0)
            maxdiv = i;
    }
    return maxdiv;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar la versión recursiva, que es más corta (y consecuentemente más fácil de leer)

```
int mcd(int x, int y)
{
    return y ? mcd(y, x % y) : x;
}
```

En cuanto a optimizar este código, no te preocupes, el código es candidato a optimización por [recursión de cola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (*tail recursion* en Inglés) y será el propio compilador el que se encargue.

A grandes rasgos la recursión de cola es un caso especial de recursión en que la recursión es lo último que hace la función, esta particularidad permite que el resultado de la función recursiva pueda pasarse a través de las llamadas en lugar de esperar a obtenerlo en el caso base. Los compiladores de C++ modernos pueden detectar esto y aplicar ciertas optimizaciones sobre el código.